# How to decode "\u0026" in a URL?

Tags: c#, url, urldecode

I want decode URL `A` to `B`:

`A) http:\/\/example.com\/xyz?params=id%2Cexpire\u0026abc=123`

`B) http://example.com/xyz?params=id,expire&abc=123`

This is a sample URL and I look for a general solution not `A.Replace("\/", "/")...`

Currently I use `HttpUtility.UrlDecode(A, Encoding.UTF8)` and other `Encodings` but cannot generate URL `B` !

Comment: `\/` head already under water, too late.  No way you'll translate the arms to /

Comment: @Hanse: This is the format `Google` use sometimes.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You only need this function

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(str);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a basic example I was able to come up with:

```
static void Sample()
{
    var str = @"http:\/\/example.com\/xyz?params=id%2Cexpire\u0026abc=123";
    str = str.Replace("\\/", "/");
    str = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(str);
    str = Regex.Replace(str, @"\\u(?<code>\d{4})", CharMatch);
    Console.Out.WriteLine("value = {0}", str);
}

private static string CharMatch(Match match)
{
    var code = match.Groups["code"].Value;
    int value = Convert.ToInt32(code, 16);
    return ((char) value).ToString();
}
```

This is probably missing a lot depending on the types of URLs you are going to get. It doesn't handle error checking, escaping of literals, like `\\u0026` should be `\u0026`. I'd recommend writing a few unit tests around this with various inputs to get started.