# In C#, how can I replace\u0026 with &?

Tags: javascript, c#, serialization, replace

I am getting a string in my C# code that comes from some javascript serialization and I see a bunch of strings like this:

```
  Peanut Butter \u0026 Jelly
```

I tried doing this:

```
  string results  = resultFromJsonSerialization();
  results = results.Replace("\u0026", "&");
  return results;
```

and I am expecting that to change to:

```
 Peanut Butter & Jelly
```

but it doesn't seem to do the replace. What is the correct way to do this replacement in C#?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990347/how-to-decode-u0026-in-a-url

Comment: Use another backslash to escape that backslash. "\\u0026" in reality is "\u0026"

Comment: Or you can use the string literal symbol e.g. @"\u0026".

Comment: @RobSchmuecker no offense here, but why didn't you flag this question as duplicate?

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair I'm not au fait enough with C# to make that distinction unfortunately!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to decode "\u0026" in a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990347/how-to-decode-u0026-in-a-url)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mark it as literal

```
results.Replace(@"\u0026", "&");
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use Regex Unescape() method.

```
  string results  = resultFromJsonSerialization();
  results = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(results);
  return results;
```

You can also utilize the Server utility for HTML encode.

```
  results = ControllerContext.HttpContext.Server.HtmlDecode(results);
```

Comment: Regex.Unescape is the valid answer

Comment: I scoured the internet before finding this. Thank you!