# Display model in UTF-8 encoding

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-mvc, utf-8

I use:

```
@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Events))
```

to display model in JSON format.

On server side I have model:

```
{"Title":"Party","Url":"site.com/events?id=1&view=table"}
```

But after on client side I got JSON:

```
{"Title":"Party","Url":"site.com/events?id=1\u0026view=table"}
```

How can I display JSON without converting of special symbols ?

Comment: Why are you using [Json.Encode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers(v=vs.111).aspx) ? Almost all projects use JSON.NET, even Web API.

Comment: ASP.NET and .NET in general doesn't need anything special to work with Unicode - all strings are already Unicode. The output of ASP.NET pages is UTF8 by default. SO uses ASP.NET and doesn't perform anything special to display strings, code, URLs. It's the deprecated `Json.Encode` method that causes the problem

Answer (score 0):

FYI, `u0026` is the unicode encoded value for ampersand `&` character.

Here are two solutions to parse `Json` correctly.

**1.** Install [Json.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) package in your project.

This is the easiest and most used method.

```
//In your view add

@using Newtonsoft.Json;

@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model))
```

**2.** Use Regex `Unescape` Method

```
@{ 
   string str = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)).ToString();
}

@{ @System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(str) }
```

References:

[1.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9331195/json-net-serialize-c-sharp-object-to-json-issue)

[2.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31033795/2218697)

Comment: The Unicode representation of `&` is `&`. This is an *encoded* value.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos , Thanks , we can also say it is the Unicode `Code` value right ?